# Entity Framework 6 creates Id column even though other primary key is defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

I defined a DataObject as:

```
public class SensorType : EntityData
{
    //PKs
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceId { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And used fluent API to make CompanyId and ServiceId a composite key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SensorType>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.CompanyId, t.ServiceId });

//No autogeneration of PKs
modelBuilder.Entity<SensorType>().Property(t => t.ServiceId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
modelBuilder.Entity<SensorType>().Property(t => t.CompanyId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

Even though a Primary Key has been set Entity Framework creates a column named Id when I run Add-Migration:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.SensorTypes",
            c => new
                {
                    CompanyId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ServiceId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Type = c.String(),
                    Id = c.String(
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Id")

                   ...
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.CompanyId, t.ServiceId })
            .Index(t => t.CreatedAt, clustered: true);

    }
```

How do I prevent EF from adding this column?

Comment: Are intentionally trying to use the combination of both fields as a compound key? If so, do you have a really good reason?

Comment: you don't need to tell the entity framework about the DatabaseGeneratedOption.None , just set the relations with Company and  Service tables

Comment: Put the code of EntityData, it seems that the Entity data contains Id and that is the reason of making it as primary key

Comment: @Hadi Hassan EntityData is a .NET class.  See my answer below for additional information on it.

Comment: I think you should not inherit from the `EntityData` class, it seems it contains an Id property, or you can add in your fluent api , `modelBuilder.Entity<SensorType>().Ignore(t=>t.Id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that you are deriving your class from `EntityData` and `EntityData` has a property named `Id`.  My guess is that EF is getting confused because there is a property which adheres to it's key naming conventions (i.e. `Id`) and an explicitly defined key.

I suspect you'll have to tell it to explicitly ignore `Id`.

[MSDN: EntityData Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt587298.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

**UPDATE:**

I'm assuming that you're working with Azure for this.  This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188393/entity-codefirst-ef6-entitydata-string-id) has some additional information in the answers which may help you find an optimal solution.

However, I agree with @Basic in his comment to your question.  I generally shy away from composite keys with EF due to the complexity (and other issues) they introduce.  I suspect a unique constraint on your `CompanyId` and `ServiceId` fields will achieve what you want without involving them in the primary key for `SensorType`.  That also means that you can just use the derived `Id` property as your primary key and avoid the entire issue all together.  I don't know if it is feasible for your implementation, but it is something to consider.

Comment: Case is clear now, the Id in the EntityData is generated as Id also, he can tell the fluent api to ignore it or just not to let the SensorType to get inherited from EntityData

Comment: Ignoring Id worked! BUT it is a violation of Libskovs substitution principle.
Is it possible to use EF and having it generate a controller without inheriting from EntityData? It provides: CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, ect. and of course Id.

Answer (score -1):

See text in documentation:

> Entity Framework relies on every entity having a key value that it uses for tracking entities. One of the conventions that code first depends on is how it implies which property is the key in each of the code first classes. That convention is to look for a property named “Id” or one that combines the class name and “Id”, such as “BlogId”. The property will map to a primary key column in the database.

to use a different key, you need to use the annotations [key], ex:

```
[Key] 
public int primaryKey { get; set; }
```

[Documentation Oficial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/keys.html)

[Tutorial Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx)